# Angular 15: Pass data to child component from parent

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm learning Angular, so forgive me if my terminology isn't quite accurate. I've provided a full version output at the bottom of this post.

This is what I have right now, and it successfully triggers a hard-coded modal. But what I want is for the modal to be an empty vessel such that I can click multiple icons, and the parent component will send the appropriate data object to the modal before it displays.

**request-membership.component.html**

```
<ng-container>
    ...
    <span (click)="toggleModal('itemOne')">Icon</div>
    ...
</ng-container>
<app-modal
  #contentModal
  *ngIf="showModal"
  title="This is the title"
  (canceled)="showModal = false">
Show the content to the user.
</app-modal>
```

**request-membership.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-request-membership',
  templateUrl: './request-membership.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./request-membership.component.scss']
})
export class RequestMembershipComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(...) { }
  showModal = false;
  data = {
    itemOne: {
      title: 'This is the title for item one',
      content: 'This is the title for item one'
    },
    itemTwo: {
      title: 'This is the title for item one',
      content: 'This is the title for item one'
    },
  };
  ngOnInit() {...}
  toggleModal(element: string) {
    this.showModal = true;
  }
}
```

**content-modal.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './content-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content-modal.component.scss']
})
export class AppModalComponent {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() bulkContent;

  @Output() canceled = new EventEmitter();

  cancel_click() {
    this.canceled.emit({ canceled: true });
  }
}
```

I've read dozens of SO and blog posts about this topic. Most of them recommend the use of  the ViewChild decorator to get a reference to the modal, then I can pump data into it. Something like this is what I might expect.

**request-membership.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('contentModal') contentModal: ElementRef;

// then within the toggleModal method
this.contentModal.title = this.data[element].title
this.contentModal.content = this.data[element].content
```

But when I drop a debugger statement in the toggleModal method I always get undefined when I try to reference `this.contentModal`.

I've tried referencing contentModal as the specific type of component:

```
@ViewChild('contentModal') contentModal: AppModalComponent;
```

I've tried adding `{static: true}` to the ViewChild declaration

```
@ViewChild('contentModal', {static: true}) contentModal: ElementRef;
```

I've tried direct references to the target component:

```
@ViewChild(AppModalComponent) contentModal: AppModalComponent;
```

But with all of these the `this.contentModal` variable is always null. I know I'm likely doing something wrong, but I'm still new enough that I can't figure it out.

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 21.5.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 15.2.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.4
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.9
@angular/cli                    15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Comment: You can do this:  <app-modal [data]="data"...  then in child component:  @Input() data: any;    No need for @ViewChild...  (though you should give data a type so it's more structured and easy to use...)

Comment: Thank you for your edits johnsharpe, but I want to make certain that potential readers get the full context of my question. I don't mind being a beginner in something, and I'll own it.

Comment: Browsermator, I understand that I can pass data into the component "on page", but I'm trying to pass data from the JS portion of the component into the child component. Adding the data parameter doesn't help me with that approach because I still need a reference to the child component.

Comment: I believe you want @ViewChild('contentModal') contentModal: AppModalComponent;  Then, before trying to access wait for it to be available via: ngAfterViewInit() { ... now check for this.contentModal }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you click on the toggle button showModal set to true and it takes a time to build that modal and add that modal to dom. so your viewchild still is null if you check it immediately. you can see that is true with a settimeout.

```
toggleModal(element: string) {
  this.showModal = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.contentModal);
   }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Jeez that did the trick. I can't believe I didn't consider that. Thank you Mojtaba! Would you mind updating your answer to include one thing though? setTimeout takes an optional third parameter, which allows me to pass in `element` and use it in the callback function. Would you please include that in your example code?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: In your code, change this `}, 100);` to this `}, 100, element);`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp